# "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT" is not working in Windows 11

Tags: java, windows, certificate, windows-11

I am running my Java app with the flag: "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT" over Windows 11 and get "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".
The application is communicating with AWS server and authenticating with Cognito.

- When I am running my Java application over Windows 10, everything is working as expected.
- When I am running my Java application over Windows 11, I am getting: "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".
- I ran again the same application w/o the "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT" flag over Windows 11, and it worked.

I do want to use this flag as sometimes my clients uses an application which intercept with the connection and my app gets their certificate for verification.

What can be the reason the flag is not working?
It could be that it's due of old Java version? I am using 11.0.4 at the moment (will upgrade soon).
Any other reasons?

One additional note, I ran "keytool -list -keystore NONE -storetype Windows-ROOT" on the Windows 11 machine and got results.

Comment: Support for Windows 11 was introduced in later JDK 11 point release:https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/products-doc-jdk11certconfig.html. Why don't you try with a newer version first and confirm if the issue still reproduces?

Comment: Does the `keytool -list` results include the correct root cert for the server? Each current (since Win8 IIRC) Windows system when installed has only a few of the trusted root certs loaded into its local store, for the others Windows downloads each one when first referenced _by Windows software_ (like a browser) from a preverified list.